# How to insert a template of text in an org file

Tags: org-mode

I have a couple org files I use for meeting notes.  The meeting note structure follows the same general pattern (slightly different for the different types of meetings).  I can always manually copy a template from a template file, or copy from the previous meeting and delete/replace text as necessary.  But, I'm being lazy about this and would rather insert a template by creating a shortcut.  That said, I cannot figure out how to get emacs to insert the text.  I know nothing of lisp, so I'm having difficulty starting.  How would I insert the lines below at the current cursor position in my org file (this is not the actual template, just example lines; if I can get these lines to work then I can do the rest of the template)?

```
* Attendants
* Updates
* Notes
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are so many options. You can define a function to insert a string, or use the built-in skeleton library like this:

```
(define-skeleton meeting-skeleton
  "A meeting skeleton" nil
  "* Attendants
* Updates
* Notes")
```

then to insert your template, type M-x meeting-skeleton at the place you want to insert the string.

Another option is yas-snippets.

Comment: That's perfect, simple is fine and I'm sure I'll get a lot of mileage out of this example.

Answer (score 0):

My recommendation would be to use the `yasnippet` package, which allows you to define snippets of text/code for specific modes (so org snippets won't be invoked when you're editing a Python file for example).

`yasnippet-snippets` will install useful basic snippets for a bunch of different modes, which can be edited at your convenience ; they are text files located in `~/.emacs.d/elpa/yasnippets-snippets-xxxxxxxx/snippets/<your_mode>/<your_snippet>` ; or deleted and replaced with personalized versions inside `.emacs.d/snippets/` (the package automatically loads any snippet located in that folder with the appropriate arborescence)

An example that would answer this specific question would be a file named `~/.emacs.d/snippets/org-mode/meeting-note` and containing

```
# -*- mode: snippet -*-
# name: meeting-note
# key: /mee
# --
* Attendants
- ${1: Default value}
- ${2: Default value}
- ${3: an absentee}
* Updates
$2
* Notes
$0
```

The "key" line defines what should be typed for the snippet of text to be invoked and it can be any convenient unique shortcut. When one types `/mee` then presses `TAB`, he will see the snippet appear and the cursor will take him through the different `$` anchors going from 1 upwards by pressing `TAB`, then ending with `$0`.

[image: yasnippet snipper illustration]